# MYSQL IF do nothing ELSE

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have a table users. When someone one to a insert new record which contains in name or in surname character diffrent from a-z,A-Z or space it will be a mistake and error occur. The code fails because after first THEN should be something, but i dont know what to put insidee. Because I only want to execute insert when if statement is true.

```
delimiter //
    CREATE TRIGGER check_name_surname
    BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            IF NEW.name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z' '.]+$' and NEW.surname REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z' '.]+$' then

            ELSE 


            SIGNAL SQLSTATE  VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect name and surname'; 
            END IF; 

    END;//
    delimiter;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have nothing to put in your IF statement then you have to 'negate' the else condition and put it in the if.

So here you will throw an error IF name is not alphanumeric OR surname is not alphanumeric.

```
IF NEW.name NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z' '.]+$' OR NEW.surname NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z' '.]+$' THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE  VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect name and surname'; 
END IF;
```

Do not forget that the AND operator become OR.